# Calculating Identical Row Name Data Entries Into a Single Row in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df with players from a given year with stat totals for them in a column. In some instances, I have multiple entries for identical players (they are the same guy, just from work done in a different league). I want to create an additional df that summarizes these more detailed tables that also combines these same player rows with an average weighted by the number of games played in each league.

Right now I might have two rows in a given year's df like this:

```
Name           GP      League            Value
Helge Grans    23      SHL               5
Helge Grans    32      Allsvenskan       3
```

But I want the new df to summarize that data like this, as well as contain the data from single entries:

```
Name           GP      League            Value
Helge Grans    55      SHL/Allsvenskan   3.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can group by the columns of interest, and `summarise` single columns (or multiple columns  with the same/different function within `across`). Here, we need to apply different functions (`sum`, `mean`, `weigted.mean`, `paste`) on different columns which we specify one by one

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
      group_by(Name) %>%
       summarise(GP = sum(GP), League = str_c(League, collapse="/"),
         ValueMean = mean(Value),
          WeightedValueMean = weighted.mean(Value, wt = n()))
```

In the likely scenario of multiple columns

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(Name) %>%
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum),
             across(where(is.character), str_c, collapse="/"),
             WeightedValueMean = weighted.mean(Value, wt = n()))
```

Comment: amazing!, I knew there was must be a simple way to do this, just didn't know what. But is there a way to make it take into account how many games they played in either entry to make a weighted average in the Value calculation?

Comment: @IanMcNamara If it is a tibble, then you can change the class with `%>% as.data.frame`